# Python Threading Error: This event loop is already running

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-3.6, discord

If your looking to run the code...make sure to do `pip install discord.py`

I have the following three python files which work together to connect to a discord server

**Launch.py**

```
from Sender import *
from Reciever import *

class Launcher:

    def startThreads(sendOB, recOB, username):
        threads = []
        recThread = threading.Thread(target=recOB.main, args=())
        sendThread = threading.Thread(target=sendOB.main, args=(username))
        threads.append(sendThread)
        threads.append(recThread)
        for i in range(2):
            threads[i].start()
        for i in range(2):
            threads[i].join()
    def launcherMain(self):
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        theSender = Send()
        theReciever = Recieve()
        Launcher.startThreads(theSender, theReciever, username)

launchOB = Launcher()
launchOB.launcherMain()
```

**Reciever.py**

```
import discord, threading, asyncio

client = discord.Client()

class Recieve:
    index = None

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        #Run through decrypter here
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        Recieve.index = message.content.find(": ")
        print(str(Recieve.index))
        #print(message.content[0:Recieve.index] + "~-#" + message.content[Recieve.index + 2:len(message.content))



    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Reciever Ready to go")
        print('---------')


    def main(self):
        client.run('TokenErasedForSecurity')

#rec = Recieve()
#rec.main()
```

**Sender.py**

```
import discord, threading, asyncio
client = discord.Client()


class Send:
    username = ""
    async def messageSender():
        channel = discord.Object(id='IdErasedForSecurity')
        while True:
            messageToSend = Send.username + ": "
            messageToSend += input(Send.username + '~->')
            await client.send_message(channel, messageToSend)


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Sender Ready to go")
        print('---------')
        client.loop.create_task(Send.messageSender())

    def main(self, theUsername):
        Send.username = theUsername
        client.run('TokenErasedForSecurity')
```

Launch.py runs sender and reciever using threads, but when I run launch.py I get this exception

> Enter your username: a Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 519, in run
>       self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 454, in
>   run_until_complete
>       self.run_forever()   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 408, in run_forever
>       raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running') RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord\HopeForBetter\Reciever.py", line 26,
>   in main
>       client.run('MzAzNjUyODYwNjY1NTI4MzIx.C9bPOA.4ISE_jmY1BYlPq937zGpjISuvAI')
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
>   line 534, in run
>       self.loop.close()   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 107, in close
>       raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop") RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

The only thing I have been able to come up with is that it is causing an exception since both threads are accessing the same file, but this doesn't seem plausible enough but I am also a novice at threading.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem on a script that reads from DB, doesn't access any files. 
did you find a solution?